# Help showing the distance function is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $X$ be a metric space and $q \in X$. I want to show that the distance function $d(q,p)$ is a uniformly continuous function of $p$.

I know how to show that $d$ is continuous, but I am stuck on how to show UC.

Given $\epsilon >0$ let $\delta =?$. Then if $d(x,y) <\delta$, then $|d(q,x)-d(q,y)|<\epsilon$.

I cannot figure out how to choose $\delta$.

Please help :). Thank you.

Comment: The triangle inequality could be useful.

Comment: I have not yet found the triangle inequality to be of great use. It might be helpful, considering it was quite helpful in proving regular continuity, but I think I need something more here. $|d(q,x)-d(x,y)| \le d(q,x)+d(q,y)$ doesn't really move things forward, considering $d(x,y) \le d(q,x)+d(q,y)$.

Comment: The triangle inequality is basically the only tool you've got, so it has to be that, one way or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$d(q,x) \leq d(q,y) + d(y,x)$ and $d(q,y) \leq d(q,x)+d(x,y)$ so $|d(q,x)-d(q,y)| \leq |d(x,y)| <\epsilon$ if $d(x,y)<\epsilon$.

Comment: $a\leq b+c$ implies $|a-b|\leq|c|$? How about $1\leq 10+5$?

Comment: You are right Vera, thanks for pointing that out. However, the triangle equality works in either case here: $c\geq a-b$ and $c\geq b-a$.

Answer (score 2):

$d(q,x)\leq d(q,y)+d(y,x)$ so that $d(q,x)-d(q,y)\leq d(y,x)=d(x,y)$

By symmetry: $d(q,y)-d(q,x)\leq d(x,y)$

This together allows the conclusion that $|d(q,x)-d(q,y)|\leq d(x,y)$

Comment: It's possible that $d(q,y)-d(q,x)\leq a$ but $|d(q,y)-d(q,x)|\nleq a$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose That's why $d(q,x)-d(q,y)\leq a$ is also necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Vera.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Glad to help. Let's keep eachother sharp. Cheers :)